# Firebase notifications multiply with hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get notifications and display them as an alert. This all works well, but for every hot reload more notifications are being received. I checked and the server always just sends one.

From my logging I can see after running the app first:

```
I/flutter (13832): New message arrived: ...
I/flutter (13832): New message arrived: ...
```

But every time I reload and send a new notification, another one arrives (so if I reload 5 times, 'new message' is displayed the initial 2 plus 5 more times" - this is also how often I have to click dismiss to remove the alert.

Here is the code:

```dart
void _handlePushNotifications(NotificationViewModel notificationViewModel) {
    debugPrint('handlePushN activated'); //test
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    messaging.getToken().then((token) async {
      debugPrint('Device Token: $token');
      var storedToken = await TokenHandler.loadTokenNoException("device_token");
      if (token != null && token != storedToken) {
        notificationViewModel.postDeviceToken(token);
      }
    });

    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) async {
      var storedToken = await TokenHandler.loadTokenNoException("device_token");
      if (token != storedToken) {
        notificationViewModel.postDeviceToken(token);
      }
      debugPrint('Token refreshed: $token');
    });

    GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>> dialogKey = GlobalKey<State>();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      debugPrint("New message arrived: ${message.data.entries.first}");
      String? msg = message.data['msg'];
      String? sum = message.data['sum'];

      if (msg != null && sum != null) {
        if (dialogKey.currentState != null && dialogKey.currentState!.mounted) {
          Navigator.of(dialogKey.currentContext!).pop();
        }

        showDialog(
          context: navigatorKey.currentContext!,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          // Prevent dismissing dialog by tapping outside
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              key: dialogKey,
              title: Text(sum),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(msg),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(dialogKey.currentContext!).pop(); //dismiss alertDialog
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();// Dismiss outer dialog
                  },
                  child: const Text('Dismiss'), 
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: it seems like the issue you're facing is related to the accumulation of event listeners when the hot reload is triggered.Every time you hot reload the  `_handlePushNotifications` is called again.